# ProgressDialog не показывается когда я использую Intent

Tags: android

Все работает нормально и второе Активити стартует, но `ProgressDialog` не показывается.

Не могу понять, почему не работает. Смотрел много похожего кода и мой код почти похож.
Кто-нибудь может найти ошибку и подсказать, как исправить ?

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Intent mIntent;
    private final int totalProgressTime = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

        new DownloadTask().execute();
        mIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mIntent);

    }

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Object>{

        ProgressDialog  mIndicator = new ProgressDialog(StartActivity.this);
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            mIndicator.setMessage("Wait..");
          mIndicator.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mIndicator.setProgress(0);
            mIndicator.setMax(totalProgressTime );
            mIndicator.show();


            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    int counter = 0;
                    while(counter < totalProgressTime ){
                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(300);
                            counter ++;
                            mIndicator.setProgress(counter);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    mIndicator.dismiss();
                }
            }).start();

        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            super.onPostExecute(o);

            mIndicator.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А что Вам нужно? Чтобы в MainActivity был ProgressDialog с отображением загрузки от 0 до 100?

Comment: нужно чтобы когда я нажал на кнопку, сработал ProgressDialog с отображением загрузки от 0 до 100 , а когда ProgressDialog достигает до 100, сработало новое Activity.

Comment: вы в корне неправильно использхуете AsyncTask, и абсолютно не понимаете, как он работает. /Прочитайте в интернете любой урок про AsyncTask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тогда нужно так:

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {

private final int totalProgressTime = 100;

private int counter = 0;

private ProgressDialog mIndicator = null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mIndicator = new ProgressDialog(StartActivity.this);
    mIndicator.setMessage("Wait..");
    mIndicator.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    mIndicator.setProgress(0);
    mIndicator.setMax(totalProgressTime);
    new DownloadTask().execute();
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mIndicator.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while(counter < totalProgressTime){
            try {
                publishProgress(++counter);
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        mIndicator.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);
        mIndicator.dismiss();
        Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Вызывать startActivity в методе onPostExecute, а цикл крутить в doInBackGround, тогда избавитесь от new Thread()

И обязательно укажите Вашу активность в AndroidManifest, как стартующую при запуске приложения

```
<activity android:name=".StartActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо вам за ответ. а можно еще вопрсо , дела в том что у меня в приложение много звуков , для их загрузки нужно около 15 секунд поэтому хотел использовать Progress Bar чтобы он сработал 15 секунд и при окончание процесса сразо открылась второе Активити. Мой вопрос.можно ли чтобы ProgressBar и Intent работали одновременно, типа две операции одновременно работали?? Я бы мог сделать SplashScreen С Progress Bar, но я изучаю Android программирование и хотел узнать как работает две операции одновременно при нажати на кнопку если это возможно конеачно.

Comment: Не совсем понял Вас. Вам нужно, чтобы во время выполнения ProgressBar уже запускалось второе Activity?

Comment: Нужно чтобы во время выполнения ProgressBar выполнилась еще одну операцию Intent и тогда , когда обе операции выполнялись, запускалось второе Activity. Я не заню , может такого нет вообще и я сам придумываю такое решение.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, что Вы подразумеваете под "выполнялась операция Intent" ? Intent это просто сущность, которая служит для вызова компонента приложения, в данном случае - Activity.

Comment: Я вас понял , большое вам спаибо.